# 3D model manipulation in Augmented Reality

Tags: 3d, augmented-reality, papervision3d, collada, flartoolkit

I'm using FLARManager and papervision3d to implement a small augmented reality hack.

my requirement is to yaw the model upon a button click.

This is what i have done so far:

```
public class AugmentedReality extends Sprite
{
    private var flarManager:FLARManager;        
    private var scene:Scene3D;
    private var camera:FLARCamera3D;
    private var viewport:Viewport3D;
    private var renderEngine:LazyRenderEngine;
    private var pointLight:PointLight3D;        
    private var activeMarker:FLARMarker;
    private var model:DAE;
    private var modelContainer:DisplayObject3D;

    public function AugmentedReality()
    {           
        start();
    }

    private function start():void
    {
        flarManager = new FLARManager("../resources/flar/flarConfig.xml");
        addChild(Sprite(flarManager.flarSource));
        flarManager.addEventListener(FLARMarkerEvent.MARKER_ADDED, onMarkerAdded);
        flarManager.addEventListener(FLARMarkerEvent.MARKER_UPDATED, onMarkerUpdated);
        flarManager.addEventListener(FLARMarkerEvent.MARKER_REMOVED, onMarkerRemoved);          
        flarManager.addEventListener(Event.INIT, onFlarManagerInited);
    }

    private function onFlarManagerInited(evt:Event):void
    {
        flarManager.removeEventListener(Event.INIT, onFlarManagerInited);           
        scene = new Scene3D();          
        camera = new FLARCamera3D(flarManager.cameraParams);            
        viewport = new Viewport3D(stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight);
        addChild(viewport);
        renderEngine = new LazyRenderEngine(scene, camera, viewport);
        model = new DAE(true, "model", true);
        model.load("../resources/assets/geom.dae");
        model.scale = 30;
        modelContainer = new DisplayObject3D();
        modelContainer.addChild(model);
        modelContainer.visible = false;
        scene.addChild(modelContainer);
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);
    }
```

Loop event handler as follows:

```
    private function loop(evt:Event):void
    {       
        if (activeMarker) {
            modelContainer.transform = FLARPVGeomUtils.convertFLARMatrixToPVMatrix(activeMarker.transformMatrix);
        }
        renderEngine.render();
    }
```

I have a handler for a button as follows:

```
    public function onButtonClicked(event:Event):void
    {
        model.yaw(1);
    }
```

It doesn't seem to be doing anything to the model at all... :(

PLEASE HELP!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try calling 'yaw' in side of 'loop' or whatever your inner loop is. Then you'll be able to make sure 'yaw' is working as expected. If it is working, perhaps the signature of 'onButtonClicked' is wrong or it isn't hooked up properly.